# Draw over legend in a Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I would like to place an arrow over a legend in a matlab plot but when I add the arrow, the legend defaults to being "on top" (see the picture, the black line being covered by the legend).

Is there a way to push a subfigure, such as an arrow, to the "top" so that it appears over all other component of the figure, including the legend? I've tried to use `uistack` but that doesn't seem to work with legends. [`uistack`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html) as the doc says should "*Reorder visual stacking of UI components*".

edit:

Very simple example: the line that I'm drawing should appear on top of the legend.

```
figure;
b = bar(1:3,rand(3));
hold on;
p = plot([0,3],[0,.5],'Color','k','linewidth',1.5); % my arrow
l = legend(b,'value','Location','SouthWest','AutoUpdate','off');
uistack(l,'bottom');
```

[image]

Comment: updated @Adriaan.  Obviously the line will be in a different spot eventually but I want it to appear on top of the legend.

Comment: Could you add a rough image of what the desired result should look like? I want to make sure I understand correctly. Did you try making the arrow using `annotation`? I second [the suggestion by @gehbiszumeis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511863/) to **move the legend**, instead of trying to make the line go above it (this is not possible since the line is a part of the axes, and the legend is like its own axes, so either the entire legend is invisible or it's covering the line, unless you use annotations, as I mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `copyobj` the current graphical axes `gca` and set its `Color` property to `none`. This method will draw the line over the legend's patches and associated texts.

Explanation : `Copyobj` will copy and display all the `axes` related to the `bar` and `line` but not the legend (legends have `axes` on their own). The display of the copied `axes` will overlay perfectly with the original one. And `'Color','none'` makes the white background of the copied `axes` transparent, thus making the `legend` visible again but visible **under** the line.

Here is the code

```
f = figure;
b = bar(1:3,rand(3));
hold on;
p = plot([0,3],[0,.5],'Color','k','linewidth',1.5); % my arrow
l = legend(b, 'Location','SouthWest');

% add some magic
hax = copyobj(gca, f); % copy the current axes to the figure
set(hax, 'Color', 'none') % set the new axes's background transparent
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make the legend background transparent - so you will see your arrow through the legend

```
figure;
b = bar(1:3,rand(3));
hold on;
p = plot([0,3],[0,.5],'Color','k','linewidth',1.5); % my arrow
l = legend(b,'value','Location','SouthWest','AutoUpdate','off');
l.BoxFace.ColorData = uint8([255 255 255 127]');
l.BoxFace.ColorType = 'truecoloralpha';
```

The ColorData Property is [R G B Transparency]

For Info: This was done using R2015b.

[image: Example output using R2015b]

Answer (score 0):

What MATLAB version do you use? `uistack` seems to not work on legends anymore, since MATLAB 2015b (see this similar [problem](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/289835-uistack-on-legend-and-axes-objects#comment_375395)).

If, as you say, the line can be appear at any place, the best workaround may be choosing the `best` legend location

```
l = legend(b,'value','Location','Best','AutoUpdate','off');
```